# input if match then filter query

Tags: sql

I want to pass a input to sql and if the input i passed is  `reg_number is '22162'` then I filter with the `mdate = '2023-10-20'` else I just filter with `reg_number is '13352'`

How do i check in where statement whether the input is passed is '22162' and then filter on that? Please help

Code I tried but with error:

```
SELECT * FROM car_details
WHERE (reg_number = ? AND reg_number = '22162' AND mdate = '2023-10-20')
OR reg_number = '13352'
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: A bit odd, if reg_number input 12345 is given, you still want 13352 to be returned?

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using (Eg SQL Server, Oracle ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM car_details
WHERE 
    (CASE WHEN ? = '22162' THEN reg_number = '22162' AND mdate = '2023-10-20' ELSE reg_number = '13352' END)
```

I simply use the CASE WHEN statement. You can also use this to modify my query as you want.

EDIT:
If you want to use AND/OR you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM car_details
WHERE 
    (reg_number = ? AND reg_number = '22162' AND mdate = '2023-10-20')
    OR 
    (reg_number = '13352' AND reg_number <> '22162')
```

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in WHERE and ON clauses.